# Can the latest versions of SharePoint support code snippets?

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, html, script, dashboard

I want to create a dashboard at work. Due to company restrictions, our best bet is to create one in SharePoint. This means we have to extract the data from an Oracle DB and use the data to create the graphics part, in `d3.js` or something similar.

The problem here is that I can't figure out how to introduce HTML or any kind of scripting into a SharePoint page. I thought embed would do it, but apparently that only works for iFrames. I searched for tutorials but they are all from previous versions of SharePoint. Then I stumbled across a page in which it was said that removing the possibility to add HTML to pages was one of the changes for 2018.

Is there any way I can turn this around or I have to find a different mean to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `code snippet` is represented in two web parts

- Content Editor Web Part.
- Script Editor Web Part.

The `code snippet` is supported SharePoint Server versions 2010 - 2019.

**Also,** if the  above options didn't satisfy your requirements, you can

- Develop your HTML dashboard outside SharePoint and display it within `Page viewer web part`.
- Or add your code to visual web part or add-on and deploy it to SharePoint.

Comment: It's odd because I can't find any of them when I try to add a web part. Could this be because I'm editing it in the browser and not on the application?

Comment: What's your current sharepoint version

Comment: I believe it is sharepoint online

Comment: Do you use modern experience or classic

Comment: As far as I know, it is modern

Comment: Seems you are using Modern experience site not classic, where the above web parts are not available in the modern site!